# Modification 3D file to the website

Tags: three.js, webgl

I use WebGL.

Is there a way to modify a .obj file (or another 3D file) for example on photoshop? When I do some change on such a file, I would like it to keep the changes I made when I load it on a website.

I know it is not possible with .obj, so is there another format to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can load some 3d files into photoshop these days, but I'm pretty sure you will not be able to modify them.
To modify .obj files you can use 3d software such as 3DS Max or Maya, or you could use an online tools such as the [three.js](http://threejs.org/editor/) editor or [claria.io](https://clara.io/)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably various ways to achieve what you want.
If I understood you correctly, you actually have multiple questions, here are some answers:

**Which 3D editing software could I use?**

If you want to perform some modification with a powerful 3D modeling tool, I would recommend to download and try [blender](https://www.blender.org/). It is completely free, but in fact a very advanced 3D modeling software.

In case you just want to smooth your mesh, simplify it, or apply some other generic operation like this, then [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) might be sufficient (also available for free).

**Which 3D model format should I use for delivering my 3D asset on the Web?**

If you use [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/) for displaying your 3D file, you can use the standardized X3D format (like OBJ, X3D content can be imported / exported in both, blender and meshlab). This has the advantage that you can use X3DOM's **inline** tag and directly import an X3D file, which means you can edit the 3D content without needing to re-convert your data for the Web.

However, using OBJ, X3D or whatever text-based delivery format might not be the wisest choice if your 3D asset is large, since this will introduce long download times. Therefore, if you have complex assets / scenes, you should also consider to convert your 3D assets to a compact, optimized delivery format for the Web, such as [glTF](https://www.khronos.org/gltf) or [SRC](http://x3dom.org/src/).